# Dictionary contain in a list which is contained in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Working with Python 3.6.  I am obtaining a JSON string after querying a webservice.  I do not have the ability to change the format of that response.

Upon a successful call, I receive this data structure:

```
{'infos': {'next_start': '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1',
           'nhits': 0,
           'nresults': 0,
           'sources': [{'indexingDate': {'vaul1': 1534796606,
                                     'vault2': 1534796562,
                                     'vault3': 1534796735,
                                     'vault4': 1534796768,
                                     'vault5': 1534796550},
                    'name': 'name1',
                    'status': True,
                    'time': '484'}],
           'version': '1.1'}}
```

How can I access the value for 'name' on *one shot*.

I tried this:

```
response['infos']['sources'](0)['name']
```

but I get this error from python:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I am obviously missing something, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Try `response['infos']['sources'][0]['name']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.

```
response['infos']['sources'][0]['name']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Simple things make a big difference.